# TeamCity Kotlin DSL: how to access agent configuration parameters from an external powershell script

Tags: powershell, kotlin, teamcity, dsl

I have a build step defined in kotlin which loads a powershell script from a path like this:

```
powerShell { 
    scriptMode = file { 
        path = "path\to\file.ps1"
    }
}
```

The file is successfully load and run, but the problem is that the script needs to reference an agent configuration parameter like `MSBuildTools15.0_x64_Path`. The parameter would be accessed via `%MSBuildTools15.0_x64_Path%` if i were using inline scripts.

Is there a way to access this variables without having to declare them as environment? i know if that was in the environment context would be just calling `${env:MSBuildTools15.0_x64_Path}` in the script, but i rather not re-declare the same things if there is a correct way to do it.

Comment: IF it's not in the System environment or you have added it, then no to using $env:. You can access any variable by name as long as it is properly scoped for visibility. [PowerShell variable/function scope](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+about+scope&form=ANSPH1&refig=28e34c35625340c789adaaa0a5b8e543&sp=-1&pq=powershell+about+scop&sc=2-21&qs=n&sk=&cvid=28e34c35625340c789adaaa0a5b8e543) is a well-documented thing in the PowerShell Help files. [about_scopes - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [postanote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote) mentioned, the problem was the scope. The agent variables are not visible to the script because it runs in a closure scope. It means you have to send the variables explicitly to it. How i did it was to define a `param` at the beginning of the powershell script, as you normally would like this:

```
param ([string] $MSBuildPath)
```

And then, in the definition of the step, which scope can access the variables, you send it as an argument like this:

```
powerShell {
    formatStderrAsError = true
    scriptMode = file {
        path = "path\to\file.ps1"
    }
    param("jetbrains_powershell_scriptArguments", """-MSBuildPath "%MSBuildTools15.0_x86_Path%"""")
}
```

I tried using `args[0]` without named parameters but you don't really know the position of the parameter without try and error because TeamCity adds a bunch of other arguments.